# Limit upload/outbound speed from Springboot service

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've got a microservice which is responsible for uploading files to Google Cloud Storage. My problem is that I need to slow it down. At the moment it will consume all available bandwidth which is normally great however not in my user case.

I've seen a few questions around rate/request limiting but that isn't what I'm after.

I can't find much on SO or Google of people attempting the same, so I'm a little unsure where to even start.

Should I be looking at the GCS SDK, Springboot, Tomcat, or something else? I'm hoping there is just a application.properties flag I can set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement this on your own.
Take a look at Google's Guava library that supports a [RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/)

To limit upload and download speed, define a `RateLimiter` instance for each and wrap them around your APIs.

```
final RateLimiter uploadLimiter = RateLimiter.create(5000.0); // rate = 5kb per second
void upload(byte[] packet) {
  uploadLimiter.acquire(packet.length);
  networkService.send(packet);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.